# Creating a file in powershell with the value containing a python script. Bracket Issues

Tags: powershell, python

I am having a little trouble creating a new file containing a basic python script within powershell due to confusion over (), "" and '' (which seem to not work in powershell).

```
PS C:\Python> new-item -path . -name Hello.txt -ItemType file -value Print("Hello world")

New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Hello world'
```

I edited it and tried:

```
 new-item -path . -name Hello6.txt -ItemType file -value (Print("Hello world"))
```

This works, but the contents of the file are wrong: ***"Unable to initialize device PRN"***

I tried quotes:

```
new-item -path . -name "Hello.txt" -ItemType "file" -value "Print ("Hello_World")"
```

But this obviously fails due to the quotes being a mess:

> New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Hello_World)'.

Any ideas on how I can get this to create a file with the proper syntax in python?

Comment: read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings - as soon as your python is multi-line, here-strings are a really nice thing

Comment: Thank you, I will do just that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/writing-double-quotation-marks-to-a-text-file-using-windows-powershell/#:%7E:text=When%20using%20the%20single%20quotation%20mark%2C%20anything%20that%20is%20contained%20within%20is%20interpreted%20literally.%20This%20means%20that%20a%20pair%20of%20double%20quotation%20marks%20will%20be%20seen%20as%20string%20indicators):

> When using the single quotation mark, anything that is contained within is interpreted literally. This means that a pair of double quotation marks will be seen as string indicators

Try the following:

```
New-Item -Path . -Name Hello.txt -ItemType file -value 'Print("Hello world")'
```

Comment: That works. I wa shaving an issue typing single quotes into powershell. I tried typing manually what you wrote, and the first ' does not appear until I press ' again, giving me a '', I can then manually delete one and it works! Strange 

Thank you